# Sum of each item returned from a PHP array

Tags: php

I am trying to get a count of active users and unactive users.

First i get all user data:
`$userData = fetchAllUsers();`

Then I write a `foreach` to get a total of the users who are active and the users who are unactive.

```
foreach ($userData as $key => $value) {
$active = $value['active'];
if($active == 1){
    $activeUsers = count($active);
    print_r($activeUsers);
} elseif($active == 0) {
    $unactiveUsers =  count($active);
    print_r($unactiveUsers);
}

}
```

All this prints is `1111111`. There are 5 users set to 1 (active) and 2 users set to 0 (unactive) in the database. So I am looking to add these up to be 5 active and 2 unactive.

I have tried`count` and `array_sum` and `array_count_values`. Nothing seems to be doing what I need. Any help would be appreciate. Can someone guide me in the right direction?

Comment: It seems the data is string, try to force it using `(int) $variable`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're inside a loop, you don't need `count`. Just increment a counter yourself. And wait until you're done with your loop to spit out the results.

```
$activeUsers = 0;
$inactiveUsers = 0;

foreach ($userData as $key => $value) {
    $active = $value['active'];
    if($active == 1){
        $activeUsers++;
    } elseif ($active == 0) {
        $inactiveUsers++;
    }
}

var_dump($activeUsers);
var_dump($inactiveUsers);
```

Comment: Ha you beat me by 18 seconds :-D

Comment: @Andy Nice =) And while your code is a bit more terse, I'd argue mine is a tad easier to understand for a beginner.

Comment: That worked perfectly! I tried that early today, but the mistake I made was not including this `$activeUsers = 0;$inactiveUsers = 0;` outside of the `foreach`.

Answer (score 3):

You need to count up a variable, e.g.

```
$active = 0;
$inactive = 0;

foreach ($userData as $key => $value) {
 switch(true) {
  case $value['active'] == 1: $active++; break;
  default: $inactive++; break;
 }
}

var_dump("Active users" + $active);
var_dump("Inactive users" + $inactive);
```